# Linux concurrency scripting with mutexes

Tags: php, linux, shell, concurrency

On my Linux server, I need to synchronize multiple scripts, written in BASH and PHP, so that only one of them is able to start a system-critical job, which is a series of BASH/PHP commands, that would mess things up if performed simultaneously by two or more scripts. From my experience with multithreading in C++, I'm familiar with the notion of mutex, but how do I implement a mutex for a bunch of scripts that run in separate processes and, of course, aren't written in C++?

Well, the first solution that comes into mind would be making sure that each of the scripts initially creates a "lock flag" file to let other scripts know that the job is "locked" and then deletes the file after it's done with the job. But, as I see it, the file writing *and* reading operations are required to be *completely atomic* to let this approach work out with a 100% probability, and the same requirement would apply to any other synchronization method. And I'm pretty sure that file writing/reading operations are not atomic, they are not atomic across all existing Linux/Unix systems at least.

So what is the most flexible and reliable way to synchronize concurrent BASH *and* PHP scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure how a mutex will help you here. If it were me, I'd simply rely on a lock or pid file - ie, save the critical job's pid into a file. On next run of either script do something like `if(process_exists(readfile(pidfile)))exit;`

Comment: @Christian Well, for the lack of atomicity in `process_exists` and `readfile` (and `writefile`) and since they aren't glued together as one atomic call, it seems to me that the logic you suggest would still leave a small window for the chance of multiple scripts starting to execute the critical lines of code at the same instant.

Comment: You should be using LockFile/flock (I think). Daemon scripts (`/init.id/*`) usually do it this way...so it's improbable they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Christian Did you mean scripts in `/etc/init.d/`? Anyway, they don't give any PHP examples.

Comment: My apologies, that is correct. I think those scripts are useful to your cause since you could try finding PHP equivalents of bash code. Well, PHP ports of the relevant system commands....

Comment: @Christian Alas, PHP shell command issuing doesn't work in the same way as in BASH, for example, as it seems, you can't wrap a sequence PHP commands around a lock file using `flock` unless you run the PHP script from a special-purpose BASH script, which makes it all quite cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: That was not what I meant, what I meant is that some posix/nix commands have been directly ported to PHP with the exact same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a PHP programmer, but the documentation says it provides a portable version of [`flock`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) that you can use. The first example snippet looks pretty close to what you want. Try this:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock

    // Do your critical section here, while you hold the lock

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Note that by default `flock` waits until it can acquire the lock. You can use `LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB` if you want it to exit immediately in the case where another copy of the program is already running.

Using the name "/tmp/lock.txt" may be a security hole (I don't want to think hard enough to decide whether it truly is) so you should probably choose a directory that can only be written to by your program.

Comment: I've got two concerns with PHP's `flock`. First is that a file being locked from a PHP script will be seen as any other regular unlocked file from a BASH script. And second, which is minor concern though, is that PHP's `flock` is not portable across all Linux file systems and won't work, for example, on NFS filesystems.

Comment: You can use `flock` from the shell as well; see @KingsIndian's answer. If you're concerned about NFS, though, you may need the standard mktemp/hardlink/stat dance. Here's one description of that, plus an alternative if you control the NFS sever: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#82521

Comment: After some tests I've performed, it seems that you're right about `flock` compatibility between PHP and BASH. And I've just looked into the source for PHP's `flock` (flock_compat.c) and, as it appears, PHP of at least version 5.3 relies on `fcntl` function for file locking, which, as stated [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock), does work over NFS as well. PHP developers even mention this NFS support in flock_compat.h file.

Comment: @DesmondHume, regarding your proposed edit to add `LOCK_NB` to the sample code: It is possible for `flock` to fail even in blocking mode. Reading `flock(2)`, I think the most likely cause would be "The kernel ran out of memory for allocating lock records," but there may be other ways. It's best to check and be sure you actually got the lock even in blocking mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**flock**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) to atomically lock your flag file. The `-e` option is to acquire an exclusive lock.

From the man page:

> By default, if the lock cannot be immediately acquired, flock waits
>   until the lock is available.

So if all your bash/php scripts try to lock the file exclusively, only one can successfully acquire it and rest of them would wait for the lock.

If you don't want to wait thenuse `-w` to timeout.

Comment: @DesmondHume I have never done PHP programming. Man page itself contains a small example in shell script if you want know how to use it. In any case, I don't think your downvote is justified.

Answer (score 0):

[fuser](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser)-based lock in Bash (it guarantees that no two processes access the protected resource at the same time but may result in negative locking attempt even if no processes access the resource, almost improbable though):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
function mutex {
 local file=$1 pid pids
 exec 8>>"$file"
 { pids=$(/sbin/fuser -f "$file"); } 2>&- 9>&-
 for pid in $pids; do
   [[ $pid = $$ ]] && continue
   exec 8>&-
   return 1 # locked by other pid
 done
}
```

Comment: So creating a file descriptor with `exec 8>>"$file"` is an atomic operation?

Comment: by opening the "lock" file the process becomes N+1 opener of the file and the for loop below the call to fuser checks if any other process had the same file opened at the time of the call to fuser, so it does not really matter whether opening the descriptor is atomic or not

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, even if `exec 8>>"$file"` was atomic, with your code it would still be possible for a script to open the lock file a nanosecond after it was opened by another script, which would result in two scripts canceling each other out after `fuser` tells them that the lock file is already opened by another process (i.e. the concurrent script). No?

Comment: @DesmondHume - you are correct, it is overly pessimistic, which is fine for most script-grade tasks. If you need to be more precise and less pessimistic (rather a theoretical consideration in context of bash/php) you should probably not use this code fragment.

Comment: .. and by "pessimistic" you meant "optimistic" ;)

Comment: well, you can't have two script accessing the protected resource but you can have two scripts not accessing it when they could, call this the way you like :)